# Cordova app with angularjs

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I am trying to make android mobile app using cordova. I have created an application in MEAN.js framework and it is working properly and now i am trying to convert this application into an android mobile application so i tried a lot but could not find a proper solution. Please help me to find the way for creating android mobile app using cordova.
Thankyou.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: 1). I created a cordova application.
     cmd>cordova create hello
     cmd>cd hello
2). Copy the angular code of my application and paste that code in www folder created by step 1.
3). give the location of the home page in congig.xml file. 
4). Add the platform in the cordova application.
     cmd>cordova platform add android

Answer (score 0):

Cordova is just a layer which converts HTML5 to native mobile app code. The thing to understand is that, although Cordova is extremely strong, it's quite low level. I would recommend you try to use [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/). It's a framework which allows you to write HTML5 code (which then gets converted to native) but it also provides a layer of Angular. So, basically porting what you have in MEAN to Ionic should be straightforward

Comment: Ionic is also not working properly with angular.js. It creates the ionic application but on emulator the application does not work properly.